# Throws an error when trying to open a URL

Tags: python

I'm running this code on python 3.6.2 and it's throwing a big error
What is wrong with the below code

```
import urllib.request

def read_text():
    contents = 
    open('C:/Users/Siddy/Desktop/Python/profanity/movie_quotes.txt','r') 
    page = contents.read()
    print(page)
    contents.close()
    profanity_check(page)

def profanity_check(text_to_check):
    connection = urlib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?
    q="+text_to_check)
    output = connection.read()
    print(output)
    connection.close()


read_text()
```

I'm trying to get the response from the url in the connection variable

Comment: What error do you get?  Typo? `urlib` should be `urllib`?

Comment: Can u paste error information here ~

Comment: It says HTTP error bad request

Comment: I corrected the typo and tried but same error

Comment: I wrote the same code in python 2.7.14, just changed first line and urllib.urlopen(), It didn't throw any error